# Android manifest merging is not supported

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use android manifest merging in intellij, but it says:

android-validator: Manifest merging is not supported. Please, reconfigure your manifest files

I believe this is not supported in Intellij as I searched in google and found a page in jetbrains community.

But I don't know why as it's related to android compiler not intellij. Is there any workaround for this?

And what tags and attributes does merger merge?

Comment: See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91916.

Comment: As a workaround you should duplicate `AndroidManifest.xml` files in the main application modules instead of inheriting them from the library module. This limitation will be addressed in IDEA 13 with manifest merging support.

Comment: I'm in the process of creating Android build projects which will contain the merged manifest which is generated by the ADT build tools.  It's a bit of a pain because these manifests have to be updated every time a library module changes it's manifest.  Perhaps you could manually invoke the merge target as part of the module build?

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who are using `IntelliJ IDEA 13`, you can enable the manifest merging option by opening **File | Project Structure | Facets**, then selecting the *Packaging* tab and enabling the `Enable manifest merging` option.

[source](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/sharing-android-source-code-and-resources-using-library-projects.html)